# For loop returning data frame with 0 rows

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through a number of objects to perform some subsetting on the data frames that are housed in each object. Also, within each data frame I am subsetting within years. I am using a character vector with the names of the data frames to pass the data into the loop, and then passing it back to the character name using assign(). The problem is that the loop does not return any rows to the data frame when assigned. Here is the code:

```
dfs <- c('df.one', 'df.two', 'df.three', etc.)
year <- NULL;
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
    data <- get(dfs[i]);
    for (j in unique(data$year)) {
        yr <- data[data$year==unique(data$year)[j],] 
        yr <- subset(yr, snowmelt.date <= sampling.date)
        year <- rbind(year, yr)
    }
    assign(dfs[i], year)
}
```

Any thoughts or ideas for other approaches would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for any help.

ratio

P.s. Please let me know if an actual reproducible example would help with this. I just thought someone might be able to pick something out by looking at the code.

Comment: there are far better ways to do this, but as a start, for subsetting by years, try this `yr <- data[data$year == j,]` j has values of `unique(data$year)` and is not an index.

Comment: Thanks, infominer. Would you mind letting me in on some of the far better ways to do this?

Comment: a reproducible example would help, perhaps a `dput` one of your data frames  paste the output of `dput(df.one)` in the question

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

First, in your inner loop you set j to a sequence of years with:

```
for (j in unique(data$year)) ...
```

then in the first line of the loop you use j as an index (row number...):

```
yr <- data[data$year==unique(data$year)[j],]
```

so if year is, say, 2012, you are trying to find row 2012 of a vector of unique years. Likely there aren't 2012 rows, so the condition fails and you get no rows in the result. Try this instead:

```
yr <- data[data$year==j,]
```

Second, I don't see the point of the inner loop to begin with. It looks like `snowmelt.date` and `sampling.date` are columns of `data`. You seem to want rows where `snowmelt.date <= sampling.date` for all years, so why not just use:

```
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
    data <- get(dfs[i]);
    year <- data[data$snowmelt.date <= data$sampling$date,]
    assign(dfs[i], year)
}
```